# Importing OpenStreetMap data in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, openstreetmap, digitizing

It is possible to import data in QGIS but ArcGIS has more features and easy to use, so is there any way to import OSM data and we can use ArcGIS tools for analysis and database creation?